# jQuery mmenu makes page automatically jump to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, mmenu

for a university project I am trying to implement a mobile menu to a responsive website. To do this I used the jQuery plugin mmenu.

Everything seems to work fine except for one thing:
Whenever I open the menu it scrolls to the top of the page instead of staying where it was. I also realized that I can't scroll the page while the menu is open (as opposed to the example here: http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/mmenu/demo/onepage.html)

My code is structured as follows:

```
<body>
    <!-- Mobile Navigation -->
    <nav id="mobilenav">
        <div>
            <ul>
                ... 
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header class="mm-fixed-top hidden-desktop">
            ...
            <a href="#mobilenav" class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
            ...
        </header>
        <div id="topbar">
            ...
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tothetop" class="hidden-desktop">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="bottom" class="visible-desktop">
        ...
    </div>
    <!-- Scripts -->
        ...
</body>
```

You can see the problem in action at http://www.mikehudson.de/BA/.

Thanks for your answers in advance.

-- Mike

Comment: check html & body in your CSS. If both are height 100% it makes these jumps

Answer (score 5):

Are you using this Plugin along with Foundation 5. If so then you can change the html, body height from 100% to auto in the global.scss file.

eg...

FROM:

```
// Must be 100% for off canvas to work


    html, body { height: 100%; }
```

TO:

```
// Must be 100% for off canvas to work


     html, body { height: auto; }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you do apply the 100% to the body/html, make sure you preventDefault() on the click event if your trigger happens to have a "#" in the href. This tripped me up.

Comment: I changed to auto, and I'm not using an anchor for that (using span) and it still jumps...